# Who is more polar: acetonitrile or methanol?

Tags: physical-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solubility

According to data dipole moment of acetonitrile is around **4** while that of methanol is **1.7** but is said that acetonitrile is more soluble in non polar solvent that methanol.

But shouldn't methanol be more soluble because it has lower dipole moment?

Comment: Dipole moment is just one of factors. More important factor is hydrogen bond between methanol molecules, similarly as for water molecules.